# what does where(:genres.in => [ "rock" ] mean in Mongoid and how can I find the reference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

anyone who knows what does `where(:genres.in => [ "rock" ]` mean in mongoid?
I saw these codes in documentation:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :country, type: String
  field :genres, type: Array

  scope :english, ->{ where(country: "England") }
  scope :rock, ->{ where(:genres.in => [ "rock" ]) }
end
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-queries/#named-scopes

Seems it means that find the document where genres contains "rock" but I'm not sure for I can't find a reference explain the `in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a small ruby DSL that pretty much directly maps to mongodb query operators. That is, this ruby line:

```
Band.where(:genres.in => [ "rock" ])
```

will translate to this mongodb query (using shell syntax here)

```
db.bands.find({ genres: { $in: ['rock']}})
```

Same for `age.gt`, etc. Here's the list of underlying mongodb query operators: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#query-selectors